# Overriding line marker filename in CPP output

Tags: c-preprocessor, compiler-flags

At work, we're using GNU CPP as a preprocessor for a custom language. The flow downstream from the preprocessor understands line markers (of the form `# 123 foo-bar.extension`) and embeds their information into the eventual compiled source.

This is all very well, but the overall process works by writing everything to a temporary directory and it does some (pre-)preprocessing on the input before handing it to CPP. This transformation doesn't change line numbers. As a result, CPP gets called on a file of the form `my-tmp-dir/foo.input-pp` and that name ends up embedded in the line markers. I'd love to be able to spoof things so that CPP instead emitted line markers of the form `original/path/foo.original.input`.

Does CPP have any command flags that would let me do this?

Comment: Can you give an example of a very basic input, the expected output, what you have done to get this expected output and what you actually get instead ?

Comment: Write an empty file called `foo.c` and preprocess it with `gcc -E foo.c`. You'll see line markers mentioning `foo.c`. I'd like to tell CPP that these should actually say `bar.c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any option for this, but can't you use a simple `sed` command to change the line markers?

```
sed -e '/^#/s,my-tmp-dir\(.*\)-pp,original/path\1,'
```

Alternatively, put a line directive as the first line of the transformed source so cpp knows what the file name is:

```
#line 1 "original/path/foo.original.input"
```

Line directives work as expected. This file:

```
#line 1 "bar.c"
int test1;
#include <sys/syscall.h>
int test2;
```

is preprocessed into:

```
# 1 "foo.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "foo.c"
# 1 "bar.c"
int test1;
# 1 "/usr/include/sys/syscall.h" 1 3 4
# 3 "bar.c" 2
int test2;
```

A mention of `foo.c` still occurs but it is immediately overridden by `bar.c`.

Comment: The sed option would work, but I was hoping to be able to emit the right lines straight-off. I tried writing my own line marker, but that seems to be copied through (good) without changing CPP's internal line tracking (not so good), so it gets immediately followed by a new line marker correcting things...

Comment: @RupertSwarbrickatBroadcom Huch? That sounds like a bug. On my local C compiler, the line directive is preserved after a line marker inserted by the preprocessor.

Comment: @RupertSwarbrickatBroadcom Are you sure this is happening? Please remember that you need to insert a *line directive,* not a *line marker* as seen in the answer I gave.

Comment: @RupertSwarbrickatBroadcom I added an example of how a line directive affects the output of the preprocessor to my answer. Can you confirm that yours is different?

Comment: You are completely right, and I was adding a line marker rather than a directive. Sorry! Thank you very much for the help.